# How to count in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to count the occurrences of phrases starting with particular keywords in Python:

```
if q.startswith('how many'):
    te[i] += 1
```

Comment: I think it should work for your purpose.

Comment: No it's not working. As I said since "how many" also starts with "how". I'm getting more counts of  "how" than  desired

Comment: It is `if-elif`. I think something else causes the problem...

Comment: Why are all indices the same? All are `te[l]`? How does `l` behave?

Comment: See the updated code. I'm looping through l. How should I change it then?

Comment: Does `l` represent a line? Then `l in q` should come first I think...

Comment: For each line, check if the line starts with how many, how much, or how in the order.

Comment: "l" is just a looping variable. "q" is the string in which I'm checking if the keyword exist or not

Comment: Please check my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` construction is OK, but you are recording different results count to same variable, and that needs to change:

```
patterns = ['how many', 'how much', 'how']
textline = 'how much is the fish'

def pattern_count(textline, patterns):
    d = {pat:0 for pat in patterns}
    for pat in patterns:
        if textline.startswith(pat):
            d[pat] = 1
            return d

te = pattern_count(textline, patterns)
print(te)

{'how': 0, 'how many': 0, 'how much': 1}
```

The code above assumes `textline` is just one string, and you really want to check the first line of it. Or the intent is different?

Comment: See the updated code. I'm looping through l. How should I change it then?

Comment: Please provide the terms to make your code complete

Comment: "l" is just a looping variable. "q" is the string in which I'm checking if the keyword exist or not

Answer (score 0):

If `q` is a string of phrases, I think you can do something like

```
te = {'how many': 0, 'how much': 0, 'how': 0}
te['how many'] = te['how many'] + q.count('how many')
q.replace('how many', '')

te['how much'] = te['how much'] + q.count('how much')
q.replace('how much', '')

te['how'] = te['how'] + q.count('how')
q.replace('how', '')
```

Comment: No it did not work. What is "something here".  See my updated code I changed "l" with "i" since it was creating confusion. Also, "q" is a really long string and I'm searching if "q" start s with these keywords or not

Comment: @Alex Isn't `q` a phrase? There must be phrases (more than one `q`s) so you need to count occurrences? So for each `q`, check if it starts 'how many,' 'how much,' or 'how' in the order.

Comment: Yes you're right. Multiple q's and am checking if those start with 'how many,' 'how much,' or 'how' keywords

Comment: @Alex As long as you check 'how' last, it should work.

Comment: I just did that. It still is counting "how many" and "how much" as part of "how". I think it's because I'm looping through same variable "i". Do I need to change that? I tried yours too it also doesn't work

Comment: @Alex Additionally, `i in q` in `if i in q` simply returns `True` or `False`. So you do not need it.

Comment: Yeah I'm checking if the particular keyword is there in "q" to begin with. If it is then add the count otherwise not

Comment: @Alex I think you should not use something like `for i in te` because dictionary items are randomly ordered.

Comment: Ok. Then do you have any suggestion as to how can I make it work? What else should I change?

Comment: @Alex Your algorithm checks each `q` three times.

Comment: Yeah I think that is why I'm getting duplicate results. But how should I change it? Should I use a list instead of dictionary then?

Comment: @Alex For each `q`, use the code from 2nd line to 7th code of mine?

Comment: @Alex You can use list. If the number of items are not that many, I think static approach is more preferable.

Comment: @Alex E.g., `open('/home/.../asdf.txt')`. List of strings? Maybe you get a set of `q`s from something and iterated through it.

Comment: I'm iterating it in the code above that of q which I have not mentioned here. In q I'm getting single string of phrases at a time. That is why I was using if "i" in q to check if keywords exist in q or not

Comment: @Alex. Ah... Oh... Then you should split it in the proper way for your purpose...

Comment: How should I do that?